# associate workflow to custom list - sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: workflow, custom-list

I'm using SharePoint designer 2010.
I have created workflow in the designer.
now I want to associate the workflow to custom list,
so I have created custom list and then go back to the workflow in order to associate the workflow. but the button "associate to list" is inaccessible. 
this is how it's look like:

[image: workflow designer - tool bar]

**where am I worng?**

Answer (score 1):

What kind of workflow have you created? I would expect you've created a site workflow, and it cannot be associated with a list, as it described in the tooltip:

[image]

Comment: thank U! so what I need to do in order to associate this workflow to some list? how can I change the workflow type (from site workflow to list workflow)?

Comment: and how can I operate this kind of workflow?

Comment: just create a workflow using adjacent button, "Reusable Workflow". Or you can use the "List Workflow" button, to associate your workflow with existing list at creation time.

Comment: when I use "List Workflow" button it give me an option to create new workflow and I d'ont have the option to import the site workflow that I have created. am I missing something?

Comment: Your current list will need to be exported to a visio type list. Then create a new list associated with what you need. You can then also export the list. Open then both in a simple editor like notepad and copy the workflow info to it - Starting Fresh is the best thing to do.